# Deleting a record from the database using Data Binding

Tags: vb.net

I have built the small application you can see in the picture below.

[image]

I am now working on the Delete button but I am stuck. Nothing seems to happen when I click on it. Can anyone tell me what I am missing please? When clicking the Delete button, I want to wholly remove the record from the database.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection     
    Dim sql As String                               
    Dim DataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter       
    Dim Datatable As New DataTable                  
    Dim ProjectBindingSource As New BindingSource
    Dim sql_delete As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            connection.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:\Corporate Reporting\2014_15\Corporate\QuarterlyReporting.accdb"

            connection.Open()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Projects_Application ORDER BY ProjectID"
            DataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
            DataAdapter.Fill(Datatable)

            ProjectBindingSource.DataSource = Datatable

            With cmbSearch
                .DisplayMember = "ProjectID"
                .ValueMember = "ProjectID"
                .DataSource = ProjectBindingSource
            End With

            NavigateRecords()

            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub NavigateRecords()
        txtProgammeID.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtProgramme.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtProjectName.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtProgammeID.DataBindings.Add("Text", ProjectBindingSource, "ProgrammeID")
        txtProgramme.DataBindings.Add("Text", ProjectBindingSource, "Programme")
        txtProjectName.DataBindings.Add("Text", ProjectBindingSource, "ProjectName")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
         Dim Project_To_Delete As String
         Project_To_Delete = txtProjectID.Text
         Dim Delete As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Projects_Application WHERE ProjectID = " & Project_To_Delete, connection)

         Delete.Parameters.Add(Project_To_Delete, OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 3, "ProjectID")
         DataAdapter.DeleteCommand = Delete

         DataAdapter.Update(Datatable)
         ProjectBindingSource.EndEdit()
         ProjectBindingSource.DataSource = Datatable
    End Sub    
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the delete command once, with a single paramter: the project id, and not with the actual project id in the sql string.

The command should be something like

```
Dim Delete As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Projects_Application WHERE ProjectID = ?", connection)
```

and you should add the parameter like

```
Delete.Parameters.Add("ProjectID", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 3, "ProjectID")
```

Also make sure the connection is actually open and not closed/disposed.

---

The idea behind the `DataTable`/`DataAdapter` is that you configure the commands of the `DataAdapter` once, do all the work within a single `DataTable`, and when done, just call `Update` and the `DataAdapter` takes are of actually executing the SQL statements

So to delete a record, just delete the specific row from the `DataTable`, call `AcceptChanges`, then update the db by calling `DataAdapter.Update(Datatable)`.

Comment: Thanks for your play. The reason why I have the sql statement built like that it is because the project to be deleted is the one diplasyed in the text box and it can change depending on what you select in the combo box. I don't really understand how I could buil the sql otherwise when the ProjectID changes all the time. Does it make any sense?